# looping through an array for the where condition pl/sql

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, iteration

Is it possible in pl/sql to loop through a number of id's that need to go in the WHERE clause of the pl/sql statement. The sql statement itself is pretty simple, but I need to iterate over a number of id's:

```
SELECT x_name
FROM table_x
WHERE x_id = {array of 90 id's};
```

How can I insert the 90 id's here so that sql iterates over them? I tried using the cursor For Loop, but I'm stuck. The code below is erroneous, but it might give an indication what Im trying to achieve here

```
DECLARE
  TYPE x_id_array IS VARRAY(3) OF NUMBER;
  CURSOR cur_x_id (x_ondz_id NUMBER) IS
  SELECT x_name
  FROM table_x
  WHERE x_id = var_ondz_id;
  loop_total integer;
  x_id x_id_array;
  name VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  x_id_new := x_id_array(8779254, 8819930, 8819931); --3 for testing
  loop_total := x_id_new.count;
  FOR i in 1 .. loop_total LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('x_id: ' || x_id_new(i) || '= Name: ' || x_name );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The expected out put would be

```
x_id: 8779254= Name: Name_1 
x_id: 8819930= Name: Name_2
x_id: 8819931= Name: Name_3
...
... etc for all 90 id's in the array
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `TABLE` function on a collection to get a list of numbers / character.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE ( sys.odcinumberlist(8779254,8819930,8819931) );

8779254
8819930
8819931
```

Here I'm using Oracle's internal `VARRAY` with a limit of 32767. You may use your own `NESTED TABLE` type.

```
create OR REPLACE TYPE yourtype AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

and then select it.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE ( yourtype(8779254,8819930,8819931) );
```

So, your query can simply be written as

```
SELECT x_name
FROM table_x
WHERE x_id IN ( SELECT * FROM 
       TABLE ( yourtype(8779254,8819930,8819931) ) );
```

12.2 and above, you won't even need to specify  `TABLE`.

`SELECT * FROM  yourtype(8779254,8819930,8819931)` works.

Comment: Thanks, this works for all the id's I need to include. Quick question, though: the yourtype table is a temporary table, that is dropped or deleted after the query is finished?

Comment: @CMorgan : You're welcome. If you think it works for you, consider accepting it so that it'll also help others. Regarding your question: No, `yourtype`  is not a database table, it's a nested table type which is permanent once created. So, creating it is a one time operation that can happen independently.

Comment: Thank you, does this affect storage on the server, is it better to drop it after I used it? Im not sure I understand correctly how this nested table works and my worry is that there will be additional tables that are only used one time, but take up space.

Comment: @CMorgan : You seem to be worrying for no reason. As I've already mentioned, the Nested Table Type is not a database Table, although the name has a "Table" in it. It also does not store physical data and take up space. It is just a specification to say what kind of data that type  will hold in memory at run time.Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375) to know more about Types