# oracle how to return a list and join to a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

In oracle is it possible to join a static list to a table?
The list I have is something like this

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I don't want to create a table for this list

But then I want to join the list to an existing table that has the ID's in it... hoping to do a left join with the list

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you use a `IN` clause instead ?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Oracle <> SQL Server.  Which one is this???

Comment: Can't use the IN clause as not everything from the list is in the table.  ANd I need to display the full list.. hence the left join

Comment: check one of  my similar answers : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611940/7998591 . You may use `JOIN`s instead of  `IN` clause as in the answer.

Comment: "Declare" your list in `with clause` whether using "generator" `with t(id) as (select level from dual connect by level <= 6)` or collection `with t(id) as (select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5,6)))`.

Answer (score 1):

You are lookig for a `WITH` clause that contains `UNION`s of `SELECT FROM DUAL`.

Like :

```
WITH my_list AS (
    select 'A' my_value from dual
    UNION ALL select 'B' my_value from dual
    UNION ALL select 'C' my_value from dual
)
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    my_list
    LEFT JOIN my_table ON my_table.my_field = my_list.my_value 
;
```

Comment: Since there won't be any duplicates (at least in this case), you can use UNION ALL to skip the processing involved in removing duplicates.

Comment: @madreflection thanks for the useful comment, updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the ID list in a CTE and then join it to whatever you want.

```
with id_list as (
  select rownum as id
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
)
select * from id_list;

ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hm2mczgx5udiig9vhryo86mfm